# Has any country ever 'sold' a part of it's territory voluntarily to another?

Tags: international-relations

I assume it can happen in a few extreme situations such as dire monetary or military needs, for example. Has it ever happened, or been proposed, in modern history?

Comment: This is clearly trivial to look up.

Comment: @Semaphore My search keywords kept returning irrelevant stuff (mostly of IMF, debts and dictators) but well...I can delete the question if it's against the guidelines.

Comment: They we're not a country, so technically not in the zone of this answer. But the native Americans living in Manhattan "sold" their land to the Dutch. Also the Dutch "got" Suriname from the English during the peace treaty of Breda (in exchange for Nieuw Nederland - New York). And the Dutch let the English watch over Ceylon (Sri Lanka) during the occupation of the Dutch Republic by Napoleon.

Comment: Texas was sold (albeit as part of a peace treaty). Also, East Germany and West Berlin sold some territory along the wall to each other (that was technically an exchange rather than a sale) in order to straighten out the border. Several countries sold territory to each other in order to deal with enclaves/exclaves.

Comment: Manhattan? Lousiana Purchase? Alaska? Gadsen Purchase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Has happened many times. Russia sold Alaska to the United States and France sold them much of the Mississippi valley. One dictator of Bolivia sold a big chunk of what used to be Bolivia to Brazil for a horse.

Comment: Could you source that Bolivian purchase? Not easy to google…

Comment: @Lohoris The guy you are looking for is el Presidente Mariano Melgarejo.

Answer (score 4):

[Louisiana purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louisiana_Purchase)

[Gadsden purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadsden_Purchase)

Comment: Florida too....